# Serialize Queryset - Group by date

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-serializer

I've got a model that looks something like:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    recipient = modes.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
```

I'd like to get the daily count of deals sent or received by a particular user for the three month window ending today. To further complicate things, I want that dataset serialized in JSON format so that I have output like this:

```
{
    "timestamp_1": count_1,
    "timestamp_2": count_2,
    ...
    "timestamp_n": count_n
}
```

So far I have arrived at a query that'll look something like this:

```
# Assume we have a user object called "user"
Deal.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(recipient=user)).extra({'date_created' : "date(created_on)"}).values('date_created').annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

Still combing through the documentation, but does anyone have a better way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Django can handle this without RAW sqls. There's a great django third-party package, [django-qsstats-magic](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-qsstats-magic) which is designed to make repetitive tasks such as generating aggregate statistics of querysets over time easier. It supports postgresql, Mysql, and sqlite.

The code below solves you problem.

```
import qsstats
import datetime

Deal.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(recipient=user))

qss = qsstats.QuerySetStats(qs, date_field='date_created', aggregate=Count('id'))

three_month_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(months=3)
qss.time_series(start=three_month_ago, interval='days')
```

Comment: Reading up on that now. Does the "time_series" method return accompanying timestamps(for the day)? Looks like it only returns the counts.

Comment: time_series returns a list of tuples. Each tuple contains 2 elements: a datetime object which represent the start of the serie and the aggregate result.